# Is it possible to run JS-file in the Google Chrome directly and debug it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

It is possible to use Google Chrome as JS-file simple editor:

[image]

It is my `c:\js\foo.js` local file. Context menu of `foo.js` tab has *Evaluate in console* menu item but it doesn't work as I expected: I don't see the `stuff...` string in the console output and breakpoint doesn't work.

Is it possible to run JS-file in the Google Chrome directly and debug it?

Comment: Highlight all/some of the code in the file and try the **Evaluate in console** option again. More details [HERE](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets)

Comment: Thank you, yes, I see console output now, but breakpoint doesn't work still (when I set it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you didn't select whole code and Chrome didn't evaluate it.

1. Press CTRL+SHIFT+P in debug tools, then select "create new snippet".
2. Then you can write your snippet.
3. Select whole code (press CTRL+A).
4. Press CTRL+SHIFT+E (or from the context menu select "Evaluate in console").

Remember, you have to select whole code. If you don't select, you will see Window object outputted in the console.

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to debug code. I didn't find any. You should consider using of Codepen or another service. Also, you can create simple HTML file and include that js file in it that you need to debug.